# Javascript intellisense by absolute path doesn't work in VS 2012

Tags: javascript, jquery, visual-studio-2012, intellisense

I'm trying to setup intellisense for jQuery. I have jquery files in another project which is not included into current solution. In my mygrid.js file I define:

```
///<reference path="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.2.js" />
```

I see that VS makes request for http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.2-vsdoc.js
but intellisense doesn't work. I tried:

```
///<reference path="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.2-vsdoc.js" />
```

No result as well. I get it working if I copy jquery-1.8.2-vsdoc.js near mygrid.js, include it into project and add

```
///<reference path="/jquery-1.8.2-vsdoc.js" />
```

But I don't like such an approach. It forces me to copy junk stuff into every project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell it's not possible to reference remote javascript files. In fact, all absolute paths in reference directives are ignored according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb385682.aspx

If you use the libraries regularly you could save them in a central location on your local machine so that you only have to download them once, then add them to the global javascript intellisense scope as outlined in the 'Smarter JavaScript references' section of http://www.hanselman.com/blog/FeaturesNOONENOTICEDInVisualStudio11ExpressBetaForWeb.aspx. 
To summarize, go to  Tools | Options | Text Editor | Languages | JavaScript | References, or you just hit Ctrl-Q to bring up the search feature, then type 'references' and click on the 'Text Editor -> JavaScript -> IntelliSense -> References' option. Click the '...' button and browse to the file you want to add, select it and then add it.

Comment: According to this FAQ http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2008/11/18/jscript-intellisense-faq.aspx VS should support such links. However it may be absolete...